# How can I convert Double[] to ArrayList of use it from msg.obj?

Tags: android, double, handler

I created a handler to received data in the UI from a different Thread.

The secundary thread get a Double[] with severl values but when I call my obtainMessage and sent it to the UI I dont know how convert from object to my orginal type Double[]

I tried this but it didnt work.
ArrayList extractData = (ArrayList) msg.obj;

How can I convert Double[] to ArrayList of use it from msg.obj?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this may work :

```
List<Double> doubleList = Arrays.asList(double_array);
```